# Go to h2 database

Tags: sql, go, h2

Is it possible to connect from Go code to h2 database http://www.h2database.com

Answer (score 5):

First of all you need to run your DB server allowing connections from any host via TCP, PotgreSQL or Web (I have done this by using a linux shell script called **runH2Server.sh**):

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=$PATH:/tmp/H2DB/jre1.8/bin

export CLASSPATH=/tmp/H2DB/DBServer:/tmp/H2DB/DBServer/h2.jar

java -classpath $CLASSPATH org.h2.tools.Server -webAllowOthers -tcpAllowOthers -pgAllowOthers -baseDir /tmp/H2DB/DBServer
```

Running the script will produce following otuput:

```
# ./runH2Server.sh
Web Console server running at http://127.0.1.1:8082 (others can connect)
TCP server running at tcp://127.0.1.1:9092 (others can connect)
PG server running at pg://127.0.1.1:5435 (others can connect)
```

Now your server is ready for client connections, you could test it connecting your web browser to the IP and port specified, for example: http://192.168.1.130:8082/login.do

Be sure to download the Go postgres driver form "**github.com/lib/pq**".

Now, from another host (or the same if you want) you can use the following code to test your connection:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

const (
  host     = "192.168.1.130"
    port = 5435
    user     = "sa"
    password = ""
    dbname   = "/tmp/H2DB/DBServer/test"
)

func main() {
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
        "dbname=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, user, dbname)

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Successfully connected!")

    rows, err := db.Query("SHOW TABLES")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("\n\n=== Tables in DB ===")

    fmt.Printf("%10v | %15v\n", "tablename", "tableschema")
    for rows.Next() {
        var tablename string
        var tableschema string
        err = rows.Scan(&tablename, &tableschema)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%10v | %15v\n", tablename, tableschema)
    }

    fmt.Println("\n\n=== Records in DB ===")

    rows, err = db.Query("SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY ID")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%10v | %15v\n", "ID", "NAME")
    for rows.Next() {
        var id int
        var name string
        err = rows.Scan(&id, &name)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%10v | %15v\n", id, name)
    }
}
```

Run it and you will have the following output:

```
C:\Go\PG_Client
λ go run PgDBClient.go
Successfully connected!


=== Tables in DB ===
 tablename |     tableschema
      TEST |          PUBLIC


=== Records in DB ===
        ID |            NAME
         1 |           Hello
         2 |           World
```

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html:

> ... it supports the PostgreSQL network protocol ... Support for the PostgreSQL network protocol is quite new and should be viewed as experimental. It should not be used for production applications.

So there is high chance that `github.com/lib/pq` driver will work with h2.

Comment: I hope performance will keep with pg driver because h2 I like for performance

Comment: I tried postgres driver but does not works with h2
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://sa:123@localhost:8082/test")
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://sa:123@localhost:8082/~/test")

Comment: with 5432 does not works.  In practite anybody used h2 in golang?

Comment: I haven't ;) It's 543*5* BTW

Comment: :) I was think tthat there was standard port

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a "native" Apache H2 Database driver for Go.

https://github.com/jmrobles/h2go

In its day I tried to use the Postgres interface but I encountered problems diagnosing bugs in the SQL syntax.

I wanted to provide a pure go alternative that would directly access H2's TCP interface.